# Rehearse slideshow and record audio and speaker with webcam

Tags: osx-lion, microsoft-powerpoint, macbook-pro, slideshow

Using my MacBook Pro unibody 2008 and OS X Lion, I am rehearsing a slideshow with PowerPoint for Mac 2011.

In some video tutorials I have seen how people record their voice, their face (using the webcam) and the mouse movement over the slides, so finally, on the video, the screen appears divided into two parts:

- one (and the bigger) with the slideshow
- a small part with speaker face

I wonder how can this be done. Right now I only know how to record audio with Quicktime while I rehearse my slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature I know from [**Jing Pro**](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/pro/).

You can see a video preview of that [here](http://video.techsmith.com/jing/2.1/webcam/default.asp).

> Give your videos personality by adding a little bit of you to the mix. You can offer viewers an introduction to your video, show them your new phone, send a video postcard...be as creative as you want. Requires Mac OS X Leopard.

I use the free version to record screencasts and think it's very productive to work with.

---

Another tool is the well known [**Camtasia for Mac**](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/features/mac/), which seems to offer the same feature. It's a more full-featured application than Jing. You can find [a tutorial about it here](http://www.techsmith.com/learn/camtasiamac/1/getting-started/recording-basics.asp).

[image]

---

Either way, this is a feature probably only found in non-free versions of those tools, but if you produce a lot of screencasts, they're surely worth spending money on.